# How to clone from a lost GitHub repository?

Tags: git, github

I would like to clone from the latest commit of the following Pull Request:
https://github.com/jenkinsci/backend-update-center2/pull/17/commits

The trick is that this Pull Request was never merged and the repository containing the latest commits from **jrichardBD** is long gone.

The user **ikedam** (commit [a5cac69](https://github.com/jenkinsci/backend-update-center2/pull/17/commits/a5cac693f7d0fbd66d092def37b7d4436be457bf) in the history) still has the respective fork, so if I clone from there (or add his repo as remote) I'm able to checkout everything up to *his* latest commit.
The latest changes, however, are nowhere to be found because **jrichardBD** reset his fork with the upstream.

Interestingly, I still can *"Browser the repository at this point in the history"* and download from there. But if I clone it, I'm unable to checkout that commit:

```
$ git checkout b19336fcbb78a5c14075b09e31f944a68539b1af
fatal: reference is not a tree: b19336fcbb78a5c14075b09e31f944a68539b1af
```

Any ideas how to checkout this specific commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub stores pull requests under

```
pull/ID/head
```

so you can [fetch the pullrequest into a `repair-pr` branch](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/) using

```
git fetch git@github.com:jenkinsci/backend-update-center2.git pull/17/head:repair-pr
git checkout repair-pr
```